# Ajuda com a função query_post WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu estou tentando fazer uns posts personalizados no meu tema WordPress, porém estou com um problema. 
Eu quero pegar sete Postagens na página principal, minha index. Porém a primeira postagem eu vou estilizar de forma diferente das outras seis. 
Eu estou repetindo o query_posts(). Na primeira eu coloquei assim:

Eu estou usando isso para pegar a primeira postagem.

query_posts('posts_per_page=1')
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post();

E para as demais eu estou repetindo o código com um parametro diferente.
query_posts('posts_per_page=5')
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post();

O problema é que a primeira postagem está se repetindo nos dois blocos. Eu queria saber se tem algum parâmetro que eu possa usar no segundo bloco para dar um "salto" começar a pegar as postagens a partir do 2.

Answer (score 0):

Galera achei a solução! 
É só passar o seguinte parametro na função query_posts():
query_posts('showposts=4&offset=1');

Answer (score 0):

Não é recomendável utilizar a função query_posts. Veja o que é dito na [documentação do WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Refer%C3%AAncia_de_Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o/query_posts):

> Nota-se que utilizar este método pode extender o carregamento da página, uma vez que a consulta principal é chamada mais de uma vez. Em alguns cenários pode ser pior, chegando a dobrar o número de processos executados desnecessariamente. Embora simples de ser executada, a função também é propensa a acarretar problemas futuros.

A sugestão é usar a classe [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) ou a função [get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/). Exemplo de utilização da classe WP_Query:

```
<?php

    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
    );

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Nenhum post encontrado</p>'
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
```